# Wizard pattern and other GUI patterns for infrequent, complicated task

Tags: user-interface, wizard, interaction-design

We are thinking of using a [Wizard pattern](http://www.welie.com/patterns/showPattern.php?patternID=wizard) to help a user complete a task.

The Wizard pattern seems to solve our problem.  We are also interested in what human factors research might have to say about the basic problem of a non-expert user needing to accomplish an infrequent and complicated task-–-are there other, possibly better paradigms for doing this than a wizard?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software usability patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted this question over two years ago and no one has offered a better interaction design pattern than the wizard.

That looks like an answer to me.